# Generating war file from spring boot application can't bring the web resources where located in other directory

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle

I changed my build.gradle file with this [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging) for making war file from the spring boot application.
But I used this feature to change the document root in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer like the followings.

```
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    logger.debug("the root of document : " + new File(documentRoot).getAbsolutePath());
    container.setDocumentRoot(new File(documentRoot));
}
```

It didn't bring the files located in documentRoot directory to the webapp directory. When I run the war through tomcat, it can't display any thing because of absence of webapp resource files.

If there is no answer, I will change the document directory to the webapps directory as normal. please give me answer. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "It didn't bring the files located in documentRoot directory to the webapp directory"? The code you have shown, won't copy any files to another directory.

Comment: In the code,  I set the webapp directory to the other place.  So if I generate war,  it did not include the directory.

Comment: Of course not. If you want to include another directory during the build, you have to change your build.gradle file. In the code you just changed the configuration for the embedded server instance, which has nothing to do with the build script.

Comment: @duni Ok, Actually I changed the webapp root using the spring boot. I overrided the function, customize() of EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface. So I thought the plugin can bring the webapp resource automatically when generating war file.

Comment: The Spring Boot Maven plugin doesn't analyze your source code and configuration to determine, if any configuration would influence the build script. You have to adapt the build script yourself.